# What is the difference between void and static void function in C?

Tags: c, static

I have a two **C** files.

file1.c

```
int main()
{
  func(); 
  return 0;  
}
```

file2.c

```
static void func(void)
{
  puts("func called");
}
```

But, if I compile the above code with command `cc file2.c file1.c`, I got the below,

```
undefined reference to `func'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But, If I remove `static` keyword inside **file2.c** and compile the above code with command `cc file2.c file1.c`, It's succesfully run.

So, I have a question, **What is the difference between void and static void function in C?**

Comment: A  `static` function is not callable from any compilation unit other than the one it is in.    Remove the `static` keyword, and the function will be callable from any compilation unit, so your program will link.

Comment: Peter's basically right, but there's an advanced scenario where a static function can be called by code in a different source file if a pointer to the function is made available to the code in the other file.  You probably don't need to worry about this yet; you probably still have to learn about pointers to functions.  The strict version is "a `static` function cannot be called _by name_ from code outside its own translation unit".

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler:  Wow. I was going to answer such Peter, but yes you are right. oh I know how to use a pointer to function, but just, we do not keep in mind all the hacks for  particular scenario. Also because, if a function must be called outside, also with a pointer, i am not going to declare it static. Ok the hack, but keep in mind it is an hack and not "you have to learn how to use pointers to function"

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - what you say is correct.   The OP gave a simple example that didn't involve making any pointer to the function available, so I didn't bother to describe such a case in my comment.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> What is the difference between void and static void function in C?

The real question should be what is the difference between `static` and `non-static` function? (the return type `void` is irrelevant, it can be `int` or anything else).

The `static` keyword is somewhat over used. When it applies to function, it means that the function has [internal linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c), ie its scope is limited to within a [translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342185/translation-unit-in-c-and-c) (simply as a source file).

By default, function is non-static and has external linkage. The function can be used by a different source file.

In your case, the error manifests itself because `static func` cannot be used in other source file.

---

When should `static` functions be used?

`static` functions are normally used to avoid name conflicts in bigger project. If you inspect Linux kernel source, example in `drivers/net` you would see many `static void` functions in there. Drivers are developed by different vendors and the usage of `static` functions ensure that they can name the functions the way they want without worrying of name conflicts with other non-related driver developers.

Comment: The `static` keyword was probably reused in unrelated contexts since introducing new keywords would break existing code using those as names.