# Are global variables by default extern? if yes, then why they have default value " 0 "?

Tags: c, global-variables, extern

I am learning C language, during which, I confront with global variables and extern keyword. I read about them on this site ([Global variable in C are static or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239834/global-variable-in-c-are-static-or-not)) and found that

> Global variables are extern by default

But I know that global variable's default value is `0`.
So, I am confused: how can it be possible that variables with `extern` keyword are only declared and not defined.

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239834/global-variable-in-c-are-static-or-not    @RobertColumbia

Comment: See also [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/).

Answer (score 3):

> So, I am confused how can it be possible, as variables with extern keyword are only declared not defined.

- Global variables are extern by default - that means they *can* be used by other [translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342185/translation-unit-in-c-and-c) (can simply be other source files).
- That said global variables are not automatically usable from other source files unless there are corresponding `extern` declaration on those source files.
- True that the `extern` keyword does not have any initialisation because it is *declaration* only. So the auto value (0) of global variables (from original source files) is obtained at the point their own *definition*.
- Note that there can only be one definition (in original source file), but as many `extern` declarations (on other source files).